# No puedo crear un registro desde una vista en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas amigos, tengo el siguiente problema en laravel. Quiero crear un registro en una tabla llamada movies que esta relacionada con una tabla category por medio de una llave foranea. Al ir a la vista new.blade.php me muestra siguiente error:

> (1/1) RelationNotFoundException
>
> Call to undefined relationship [category] on model [App\Category].

Tabla Movies

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 50)->required();
            $table->string('description', 50)->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Modelo Movie

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'movies';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'category_id'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Modelo Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'categories';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];
  protected $guarded = ['id'];

  public function movies()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movie');
  }
}
```

Controlador MovieController@create

```
public function create()
{
  $categoria = Category::with('category')->get();
    return \View::make('new', compact('categoria'));
}
```

Vista crear new.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'movie.store', 'method' => 'post', 'novalidate']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                      {!! Form::label('full_name', 'Nombre') !!}
                      {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control' , 'required' => 'required']) !!}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      {!! Form::label('email', 'Descripci&oacute;n') !!}
                      {!! Form::text('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control' , 'required' => 'required']) !!}
                  </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                      {!! Form::label('category', 'Categoria') !!}
                      <select name="category_id">
                                                @foreach($categoria as $catego)
                                                    <option value="{{$catego->category->id}}">{{$catego->category->name}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                      {!! Form::submit('Enviar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success ' ] ) !!}
                  </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{$categoria}}
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás intentando precargar por medio de Eager Loading una relación inexistente entre el modelo Category y otro "category" (cuya relación no está definida en el modelo), esto es lo que intentas hacer con el método `with()`.

Si lo que deseas es simplemente obtener todas las categorías, probablemente solo necesites hacer esto en el controlador:

```
$categoria = Category::get();
```

Y en la vista, en el select:

```
@foreach($categoria as $catego)
   <option value="{{$catego->id}}">{{$catego->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo me sirvió mucho pude ya crear registros.